# Как удалить тег по его контенту?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Решил убрать виджет с мордами (вконтакте), который висит почти на каждом сайте, и нигде не могу найти инфу по удалению тега по его контенту или удалению тега с определенным контентом (содержанием). Буду рад совету в этом вопросе.

Вот код, который надо удалить:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<div><div id="vk_group"></div></div>');
  $(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("vk_group")) {
      VK.Widgets.Group("vk_group", {mode: 0, width: "240"}, 00000000);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @anlima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Будут удалены все тэги script, внутри которых встречается строка `document.write('<div><div id="vk_group"></div></div>');`. Если это не подходит, можна выбрать другую строку из имеющихся. Этот ваш скрипт виджета таки будет исполнен перед удалением. Размещайте скрипт, который удаляет скрипт виджета, перед скриптом виджета.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('script').each(function() {
            var curreScriptTagCode = $(this).html()
            if (curreScriptTagCode.indexOf("document.write('<div><div id=\"vk_group\"></div></div>');") != -1) {
                $(this).remove()
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: Что-нибудь пишет в консоль броузера? Как добавляете скрипт? Я у себя запускаю, и соответствующий тэг удаляется, но программа успевает создать `<div id="vk_group">`.

Comment: Из консоли удаляет. но вот в скрипте greasemonkey не удаляет, я подозреваю, что его, возможно, надо будет запускать несколько раз с определенным интервалом, только как это реализовать, я еще не знаю...